# C++ Error: C4430 and C2143 Error at an impossible place

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I tried to search the answer to this error on the internet, but the problem always seems to be that someone forgot to add the return specifier int to the main function. It's weird, because the error is thrown on a line where nothing can possibly be wrong:

```
#ifndef ResMan_H
#define ResMan_H

#include "Loader.h"
#include <iostream>

template<class Res>
class ResourceManager {

private:
    std::map<int, Res*> resourceList; //C4430 & C2143
    Loader<Res> * loader;

public:
    ResourceManager(Loader<Res> * loader);
    void load(int key, std::string);
    Res* request(int key);
    void unload(int key);
    void dispose();
};

#endif
```

Error is thrown on line:

```
std::map<int, Res*> resourceList;
```

The Loader.h file simply contains:

```
#ifndef Loader_H
#define Loader_H

#include <iostream>

template<class Res>
class Loader {

public:
    virtual Res* loadFromFile(std::string filePath);

};

#endif
```

The errors are saying that I missed a ";" and that I forgot a type specifier somewhere, but this isn't true. I tried restarting VS13 (Sometimes it doesn't give me those weird errors anymore after a restart), but that did not help.

Edit: It would be nice to know why a question gets downvoted, so that I can avoid doing the same error on my next question. Thanks.

Comment: Check the content and end of `Loader.h`

Comment: `#include <map>` perhaps?

Comment: @Columbo Added the content in the post. I can't figure out anything wrong there either.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks! It worked! I thought it would be enough if I include iostream. Could you maybe post your answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Still weird though that it threw 2 errors completely unrelated to the problem.

Comment: @Fly `<iostream>` is solely for IOstreams, as the name implies. And why would `<iostream>` include `<map>`?

Comment: @Columbo Oh, right. I thought it would include the whole std namespace. My bad, sorry ^^

Comment: @Fly: Yes, it can, but relying on any header including more symbols than specified is a really bad idea. It breaks too easily, when you change the library (version or provider).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to place

```
#include <map>
```

In your header.

Thus the compiler could not resolve the type `std::map<int, Res*>`.